# Extract some of the fields from plain .sql file and write all rows to .csv using php

Tags: php, sql, csv, extract

I have an .sql file which contains some data like "first_name", "last_name", "email" etc.

What I want to achieve is extraction of some of the fields (let's say "first_name" and "last_name" only) and save them into .csv file.

Comment: .sql is generated by mysqldump ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the database, then you can use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
    INTO OUTFILE "/path/to/file.csv" 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    FROM mytable;
```

Comment: It'll be a bit difficult to run this on plain sql file.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, however it worked as part of workaround.